# how to RSSFeeds from Multiple Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, feed

i am gettting RssFeeds for my site and it is showing.But how to get RSS Feeds from multiple sites and need to show in line from 1st site three feeds,2nd site three feeds etc;mostly from CNN,BBC

here is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BlogFeeds();
}
protected void BlogFeeds()
{
    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList items = default(XmlNodeList);
        xmldoc.Load("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_americas.rss");
        xmldoc.Load("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#");
        items = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");
        // use XPath to get only items
        string title = string.Empty;
        string link = string.Empty;
        string desc = string.Empty;
        string pubDesc = string.Empty;
        string st = "";
        int i = 0;

        foreach (XmlNode item1 in items)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node1 in item1.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node1.Name == "title")
                {
                    title = node1.InnerText;
                }
                if (node1.Name == "link")
                {
                    link = node1.InnerText;
                }
                if (node1.Name == "description")
                {
                    desc = node1.InnerText;
                    if (desc.Length > 90)
                    {
                        pubDesc = desc.Substring(0, 90);
                    }
                    else
                    { pubDesc = desc; }
                }
            }
            st += "<a target='_blank' href='" + link + "'>" + title + "</a><br />" + pubDesc + " ... " + "<div style='border-bottom: 1px dotted #84acfd; padding-top:10px;'></div></br>";
            i++;
            if (i == 3)
                break;
        }
        lblBlogOutput.Text = st;
    }
    catch (Exception eax)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look at the SyndicationFeed class, it exposes the RSS Feed in an easy format making it simpler to retrieve and bind feeds to UI controls.  MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call .Load() and have it append to the XmlDocument.

Have a look at this modified version of the code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BlogFeeds();
        }
        protected void BlogFeeds()
        {

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNodeList items = default(XmlNodeList);

                xmldoc.Load("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_americas.rss");
                items = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");
                ReadTopArticles(items);

                xmldoc.Load("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#");
                items = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");
                ReadTopArticles(items);

            }
            catch (Exception eax)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        private void ReadTopArticles(XmlNodeList items)
        {
            string title = string.Empty;
            string link = string.Empty;
            string desc = string.Empty;
            string pubDesc = string.Empty;
            string st = "";
            int i = 0;

            foreach (XmlNode item1 in items)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node1 in item1.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (node1.Name == "title")
                    {
                        title = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    if (node1.Name == "link")
                    {
                        link = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    if (node1.Name == "description")
                    {
                        desc = node1.InnerText;
                        if (desc.Length > 90)
                        {
                            pubDesc = desc.Substring(0, 90);
                        }
                        else
                        { pubDesc = desc; }
                    }
                }
                st += String.Format("<a target='_blank' href='{0}'>{1}</a><br />{2} ... <div style='border-bottom: 1px dotted #84acfd; padding-top:10px;'></div></br>", link, title, pubDesc);
                i += 1;
                if (i == 3)
                    break;
            }
            lblBlogOutput.Text += st;
        }
```