# need to get Rss Feed in count (i.e per site 5 feeds)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, rss

i am getting Rss Feed from my DB but i am getting all feeds and everytime when i run my code in DB Data is adding.Show i need to show Rss Feed in Count and how to ignore the already added feed in DB and in source code i am showing in Repeater control

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    RssDC rssDC = new RssDC();
    RssBAL rssBAL = new RssBAL();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) { 
        //List<RSSFeed> rssFeedList = new List<RSSFeed>();
        //var item = BlogFeeds("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_americas.rss",  3, rssFeedList);
        //var item2 = BlogFeeds("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#",  3, rssFeedList);
        //var item3 = BlogFeeds("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/Election2012", 3, rssFeedList);
        //Repeater1.DataSource = item3;
        //Repeater1.DataBind();

        BlogFeeds("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_americas.rss", 3);

        fillRssFeeds();
        }

    }

    private void fillRssFeeds()
    {        
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = rssBAL.GetRssFeeds(rssDC);

        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void BlogFeeds(string url,  int count)
    {

        try
        {

            RssDC rssDC = new RssDC();
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNodeList items = default(XmlNodeList);
            xmldoc.Load(url);
            items = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");

            // use XPath to get only items

            foreach (XmlNode item1 in items)
            {

                foreach (XmlNode node1 in item1.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (node1.Name == "title")
                    {
                        rssDC.Title = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "link")
                    {
                        rssDC.Link = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if(node1.Name == "guid")
                    {
                        rssDC.RSS_ID = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "description")
                    {
                        rssDC.Description = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "pubDate")
                    {
                        rssDC.DatePublished = node1.InnerText;
                    }


                }
                rssDC = RssBAL.AddRssFeed(rssDC);


            }

        }
        catch (Exception eax)
        {
            //return;
        }

        //return rssFeedList;
        //Repeater1.DataSource = rssFeedList;
        //Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Please post up relevant source code

Comment: hello Curt added aspx.cs code can you give me suitable suggestion..waiting for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a certain number of articles retrieved, based on the input parameter you supply from BlogFeeds(), you could try something like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode item1 in items)
            {
                int currentIterationIndex = 0;

                foreach (XmlNode node1 in item1.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if(currentIterationIndex >= count -1)
                    {
                        continue; //or break; would probably be better.
                    }

                    if (node1.Name == "title")
                    {
                        rssDC.Title = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "link")
                    {
                        rssDC.Link = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if(node1.Name == "guid")
                    {
                        rssDC.RSS_ID = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "description")
                    {
                        rssDC.Description = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "pubDate")
                    {
                        rssDC.DatePublished = node1.InnerText;
                    }

                    currentIterationIndex += 1;
                }
                rssDC = RssBAL.AddRssFeed(rssDC);


            }

        }
```

Comment: hello but i am getting Rss Feeds a lot i need control the count to 3 and need to get from three sites (i.e top 3 headlines).currently i gave Rss Feed url in page load but unable to control its count

Comment: hello this code helped me to move to another level.but actually in pageload i am giving RssFeed Url and main sole aim is to get Rss Feeds from 3sites in count (i.e need to get 3 headlines from every RssFeed site) and more over if the news has been reposted in frontline have to ignore by using Guid unique key.after this code i am getting added when ever Fresh Feed is coming.

                   thanks in advance

Comment: Hi mohan11, does my code answer your first question? If it does, I think you should create a new question if you have any more questions.

Comment: yeah really it helped me a lot seany 84.worked out well i want to mark it as answer but it need 15 reputation...but really thanks for your timely answer

Comment: Glad I could help. When you do create your new question, make sure to link it back to this one so other people can see the history of the problems and it will give you better answers. You can mark it as the answer whenever you get to 15 reputation points. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have answered your question in full. Please see your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109521/how-to-rssfeeds-from-multiple-websites

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7464/discussion-between-mohan111-and-seany84)